# Spliting trapezoid to traingles with constant angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have this right-angled trapezoid
[image: right angled trapezoid 1]
that I want to split in $n$ parts in such way that each diagonal will be at the same angle to the bottom line. I'm starting with:

- first and last height - $h_0$, $h_n$
- angle between top and bottom line - $\alpha$
- length of bottom line - $X$

I think I'm able to calculate it for $n = 2$ just from ratio (below) but anything more is above me.
$$\frac{h_0}{|P_0 P_1|} = \frac{h_2}{|P_1 P_2|}$$

Real world example is [tapered truss](https://images.app.goo.gl/sBmsGJ61gqPcu51y6) and its webs. I really appreciate any help, even stating that it is impossible to calculate. I haven't thought about trigonometry that much in the last 10 years and I'm sick of it.

---

EDIT #1:

Thank you for answering! I should have guessed that my description will put you in solving this specific case when I'm searching for more broad solution. Nevertheless, your answers guided me on the right track, and I have one piece of the puzzle. Going with @CiaPan idea I found the ratio:
$\left(\frac{h_n}{h_0}\right)^\frac{2}{n}$
that helped me in calculating distances between $P$ points.

But expanding my question to this trapezoid
[image: this trapezoid 3]
as well to the cases with odd $n$ parts seems making this approach invalid as I don't know anything about similar triangles ($P_0, y_1, P_2$ and $P_2, y_3, P_n$).
My only idea for this case is to find ratio ($R$) between bases of each triangle:
$$\frac{|P_0 P_2|}{|P_2 P_4|}=\frac{|P_2 P_4|}{|P_4 P_6|}=...=\frac{|P_{n-4} P_{n-2}|}{|P_{n-2} P_n|}$$
I'm almost certain that it won't help with odd $n$ cases but this would allow me to calculate everything the same way as in the first case. The only thing I know is that sum of this geometrical sequence would equal to the length of bottom line $X = |P_0 P_2| \cdot \frac{1-R^n}{1-R}$.

Thank you once again I look forward to solving this with you!

Answer (score 2):

First, you can't write $\frac{h_0}{|P_0P_1|}=\frac{h_1}{|P_1P_2|}$ because those are not similar triangles.  However, you can write $\frac{h_0}{|P_0P_1|}=\frac{h_2}{|P_1P_2|}$.

Also, you don't need $X$ if you have the other information - in fact you could calculate $$\frac{h_n-h_0}{X}= \tan(\alpha)\text{,}$$ but we do not need to bother with this as we will not use $X$.

Notice from your picture that $n$ must be even, so we write $n=2N$ for some $N$. Let $m=\tan(\alpha)$ be the slope of the top line, and let $k=\tan(\beta)$ be the slope you are trying to find.

You have $k=\frac{h_0}{|P_0P_1|}=\frac{h_2}{|P_1P_2|}$, and  $m=\frac{h_2-h_0}{|P_0P_1|+|P_1P_2|}$.

Therefore
\begin{align*}
h_2-h_0 &= m (|P_0P_1|+|P_1P_2|) = \frac{mh_0}{k}+ \frac{mh_2}{k}\\
h_2(1-\frac{m}{k}) &= h_0(1+\frac{m}{k})\\
h_2 &= h_0\left(\frac{1+\frac{m}{k}}{1-\frac{m}{k}}\right)\\
& = h_0\left(\frac{k+m}{k-m}\right)\text{.}
\end{align*}
This same geometry holds for $h_{2i+2}=h_{2i}\left(\frac{k+m}{k-m}\right)$ for any $i$, so multiplying them all together gives
\begin{align*}
h_n & = h_{2N} =h_0\left(\frac{k+m}{k-m}\right)^N\\
\left(\frac{h_n}{h_0}\right)^{\frac{1}{N}} &= \frac{k+m}{k-m}\\
\left(\left(\frac{h_n}{h_0}\right)^{\frac{1}{N}}-1\right)k &= \left(\left(\frac{h_n}{h_0}\right)^{\frac{1}{N}}+1\right)\cdot m\\
k &= \left(\frac{\left(\frac{h_n}{h_0}\right)^{\frac{1}{N}}+1}{\left(\frac{h_n}{h_0}\right)^{\frac{1}{N}}-1}\right)\cdot m
\text{.}
\end{align*}
Since $k=\tan(\beta)$ and $m=\tan(\alpha)$, you have (resubstituting $N=\frac{n}{2}$, just be careful to remember that $n$ must be even):

$$\beta = \tan^{-1}(k) = \tan^{-1}\left(\left(\frac{\left(\frac{h_n}{h_0}\right)^{\frac{2}{n}}+1}{\left(\frac{h_n}{h_0}\right)^{\frac{2}{n}}-1}\right)\cdot \tan(\alpha)\right)\text{.}$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think that I understand what is going on but I must have made some mistake in implementing this solution. Do you think this solution can be adjusted to cover all other cases that I have raised in my edit? Odd $n$ also can occur. For now I successfully applied @CiaPan solution but it is quite limited.

Comment: @radrzan I'm having trouble editing the main answer for some reason but you can indeed generalize (sorry I was presumptuous assuming $n$ even). I'll try to explain a bit here in comments for now, then maybe can give more detail in main solution later.

First off, if $n$ is even, it doesn't matter if you start from top or bottom, you get the same $k$, thus same $\beta$, as in my main post.  

Second, regardless of number of segments, ratio of $\frac{h_{i+1}}{h_i}$ is always either $\frac{k+m}{k}$ (when diagonal starts from top left), or $\frac{k}{k-m}$ (when diag starts from bottom left).

Comment: Third.  Multiplying the ratios $\frac{h_{i+1}}{h_i}$ all together gives you very similar equation to main post, but in case where $n$ is odd, it will generally not be solvable without technology of some kind (its an equation with one unknown variable, "$k$").  ALSO the equation will be slightly different depending on whether you start from top left or bottom left, since you will get one more factor of $\frac{k+m}{k}$ in the first case and one more factor of $\frac{k}{k-m}$ in the second.  But in either case it will not be solvable without tech, unless I'm being silly and missing something.

Comment: Fourth.  Once you do solve for $k$, you can get the lengths of the bottom segments $|P_iP_{i+1}|$ as follows.  If diagonals start from top left, your bottom segments start out with single segment of length $\frac{h_0}{k}$, then next two have length $\frac{h_0}{k}\left(\frac{k+m}{k-m}\right)$, next two length $\frac{h_0}{k}\left(\frac{k+m}{k-m}\right)^2$, etc.  If diags start from bottom left, first two segments are length $\frac{h_0}{k-m}$, next two length $\frac{h_0}{k-m}\left(\frac{k+m}{k-m}\right)$, next two length $\frac{h_0}{k-m}\left(\frac{k+m}{k-m}\right)^2$, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Find similar and congruent triangles and notice how their similarity implies a geometric progression: $$h_0 : h_2 = h_2 : h_4 = \ldots = h_{2n} : h_{2n+2}$$
Same ratio will apply to sequences of every second triangle's base, which will define a division of $X$ into segments.

Comment: Thank you! Your lead was great and I solved this specific case. Unfortunately there are more as diagonal lines can start from the top of the trapezoid as well as there can be odd $n$ number of parts. See my edit if you are interested.